# itext PDF 5 version how to add a vertical line separator to a table with 2 cells

Tags: java, itext

[image]

[image]

I want to add a vertical line separator to a table with 2 cells . Want the line to be aligned at the center of the contents (2 text cells)

Adding images of actual & expected .

```
private PdfPTable createHeader() throws Exception {

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    BaseColor headerColor = new BaseColor(235, 244, 252, 1);

    table.addCell(createCell(getMemberDetails(),78,0,0,10,0,1, headerColor, ALIGN_LEFT, ALIGN_JUSTIFIED));
    table.addCell(createCell(getAccountDetails(),78,0,0,10,0,1, headerColor, ALIGN_LEFT, ALIGN_JUSTIFIED));

    return table;
  }

  private Paragraph getAccountDetails() {
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

    Font labelFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(85, 85, 85));
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase("ACCOUNT",labelFont);
    paragraph.add(phrase);
    paragraph.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

    labelFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(51, 51, 51));
    phrase = new Phrase("000001",labelFont);
    paragraph.add(phrase);

    return paragraph;
  }

  private Paragraph getMemberDetails() {
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

    Font labelFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(85, 85, 85));
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase("MEMBER",labelFont);
    paragraph.add(phrase);
    paragraph.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

    labelFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(51, 51, 51));
    phrase = new Phrase("John Doe",labelFont);
    paragraph.add(phrase);

    return paragraph;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding cells with 0 width border?  something like this?

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 2", new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL, Color.YELLOW)));
cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER | Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;
cell.BorderWidthBottom = 0f;
cell.BorderWidthTop = 0f;
cell.BorderWidthLeft = 10f;
cell.BorderWidthLeft = 0f;
table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell("Cell 3");
```